# REST django field validator based on other field in same model

Tags: python, django, rest

How do I validate the model attributes with validator based on other field in same model using django ModelSerializer. Example model code:

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = (
            'name','mobile','email','source',
            'referred_by_biz',
            'referred_by_ap')
```

If source entered is 'B', then referred_by_biz'(foreignkey value) cannot be blank and if source is 'A', then 'referred_by_ap' cannot be blank/null (foreignkey). How can I accomplish this at usign validate method? I have just started using REST framework. I am using curl to get the url for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably work :

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['source'] == 'A' and attrs['referred_by_ap'] == '':
        raise serializers.ValidationError('referred_by_ap cannot be blank')
    if attrs['source'] == 'B' and attrs['referred_by_biz'] == '':
        raise serializers.ValidationError('referred_by_biz cannot be blank')
    return attrs
```

Comment: I have tried the above it didn't work, hence I posted

Comment: What part doesn't work? Is the method never called (it will only be called if all other validation passes) or do the invalid values still pass and not raise an exception?

Comment: method never called nor does it raise any exception

Comment: Ok but do some validation errors occur anyway? I don't know how your model is defined, but foreign keys could raise their own field required errors, if they are not defined with blank=True and null=True, and that could be the reason validate is never called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2977085/zorba foreignkeys are indeed called with blank=True and null=True. Here selection of the foreign key depends on the source value. Hence, the logic is implemented that way. Can you suggest how to enforce the validation in this case?

Comment: Hmm, everything seems fine to me then... The only puzzling thing is that validate is never called, maybe it could be some silly error somewhere else, like wrong serializer class on view? I am all out of ideas sorry.